# Can Rush continue without Neil Peart?

Tags: rock, prog-rock

Must Rush be done because Peart is done?

Was there some problem with Ron Wood becoming a Rolling Stone? ... or Jason Bonham playing with The Who?

There are numerous drummers, studio, touring, amateurs who can competently play Neil's parts... and more than one who could contribute to new material.

Have Geddy and Neil made any statements in regard to a new drummer?

Answer (score 1):

There's really two questions here.  **Who, legally owns the name "Rush," and what makes up the real soul and identity of the band Rush?**

It's worth noting here that [the band existed for 6 years](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rush_(band)) before Peart joined, so it's unlikely that he owns the rights to the name.  On the other hand, most of the band's successes came post-Peart, so **he's arguably an essential part of what most people identify as "Rush."**

From interviews, it seems like there's no actual barrier to Rush continuing on without Peart, but that there's also **no interest** in that by the remaining members.  They're all technically retirement age by now, and don't seem to have much interest in the rigors of touring, nor have they released any new music since 2012:

> "I'd say I can't really tell you much other than that there are **zero plans to tour again**. As I said earlier, we're very close and talk all the time, but we don't talk about work. We're friends, and we talk about life as friends. I can't really tell you more than that, I'm afraid. I would say there's no chance of seeing Rush on tour again as Alex, Geddy, Neil. But would you see one of us or two of us or three of us? That's possible.
>
> [Geddy Lee](https://www.rollingstone.com/music/music-news/rush-geddy-lee-interview-prog-rock-hemispheres-738828/) in *Rolling Stone*, 2018.

Comment: "But would you see one of us or two of us or three of us? That's possible."

Yep ... so why do you say there's no interest?  Geddy seems to very much want to ... he's never said he's done. But would I see Geddy Lee and band under the name Rush?  Nope.  However I would see 'GedPlus' in an All-Star Ringo type situation playing multiple shows, multiple says, one city at a time ... they'd have NO problem getting players.

Very unlikely an individual would owns a significant trademark. That person sets up a corporation, production company, for protection.

Comment: You didn't ask if Geddy was done.  You asked if "Rush" was done.  Please note his quote "no chance of seeing *Rush* on tour again".

Answer (score 1):

Must they be done?  No.

Did they *choose* to be done?  Yes.

The Who, you may note, did their first "Farewell Tour" in 1980.  They'd drag Entwistle's corpse on stage if they thought it'd make them an extra buck.  The Stones have had numerous personnel changes.  Most bands do this routinely.  A select few bands, ones with integrity, know that every member is part of the "heart and soul" of the band and decide that once a member leaves or dies, that band is done.  Led Zeppelin did this, with a few "reunion" exceptions, once John Bonham died.  I can't imagine U2 continuing if one of their members called it quits.  Joy Division, Beastie Boys, Nirvanna...  All called it quits after losing a band member.  Even though Linkin Park had 2 other band members in the beginning, they were gone by the time they had renamed themselves Linkin Park, and they haven't done anything since Chester Bennington killed himself in 2017.

Comment: Is it true that Geddy doesn't want to be done but both Neil and Alex do?  What you say about The Who is absolutely right and unfortunately Roger is to 'blame' for that as Pete has noted that Roger lays on a guilt trip for hurting his income ... and John's serious gambling debt in 1980. Its very sad that Pete says he needs the money at age 74 given his incredible lifetime of investment (If he needed the money to buy a boat why did he give $11M pounds else he'd say he's now doing it for charity ... and did note a one million cost for his son-in-laws full spectrum autistic child.)

Comment: Thank you for nothing the other bands that ceased when a member leaves.

Comment: @RandyZeitman - When you've formed an amazing bond with a group of friends that you're still incredibly tight with, and you've toured the entire planet and make gazillions of dollars, WHY would you want to do that with a replacement member?  Imagine you had 3 brothers and one of them dies.  Would you go out and adopt a new brother and still enjoy the camaraderie you had when it was 3 brothers?

Geddy still wants to play, but not as Rush.  Alex still wants to play, but not as Rush.  I'm sure they'll tour together at some point, but not as Rush.  Rush is the past, now.

Comment: Yep... it doesn't have to be as Rush. I'd frankly like an 'All-Star' review as per Ringo.